# Calculate Side when Radius and other Side is known?

Tags: geometry, geometric-algebras

[image]

Can anybody please help me calculating the side when Radius and other side is known??

Please refer above attached image for more elaboration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Right triangle]

construct a right triangle as shown

hypotenuse $= R$, side $= 350$ and side $= R-x$

Comment: Thanks. Perfect & Simplest Method :)